# Building String from UART Characters - Home Learning C

Tags: string, concatenation, pic, uart

I'm working with a PIC and have successfully got a single character received over the UART, however I now need to capture a incoming sequence of characters, build up a string and perform a action after receiving a carrage return. I have some prior experience with PHP and thought things would be much easier than its turned out to be.

I've modified my simple code with the working UART functions to attempt to concatinate the received characters as follows and build up a string:

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include "string.h"

unsigned char InChar;
char Temp[5];
char Command[32];

void UART_Demo_Command_INT(void) 
{    
    if(eusartRxCount!=0) 
    {   
        InChar=EUSART_Read();  // read a byte for RX
        strcat(Command,InChar); //concat Command with InChar, result in Command
        printf = printf("Command String: %s \n", Command);
    }  

}
```

I'm receiving a number of errors:

```
UART_Demo.c:115:24: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'unsigned char' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
        strcat(Command,InChar); //concat Command with InChar, result in Command
                       ^~~~~~
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\pic\include\c99\string.h:36:55: note: passing argument to parameter here
char *strcat (char *__restrict, const char *__restrict);
                                                      ^
UART_Demo.c:116:16: error: non-object type 'int (const char *restrict, ...)' is not assignable
        printf = printf("Command String: %s \n", Command);
        ~~~~~~ ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

After spending a number of hours trying to fix this and getting nowhere I'm hoping some of you can help.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested the problem was because my received characters are just...characters, not a string which would normally have a termination \0 character at the end, therefore the strcat (Concatinate strings) function didn't work.

As a fix I just added \0 to the end of InChar then strcat worked.